# Change style based on selected value with dynamic IDs Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this blade file which is using Laravel livewire. I have added dynamic add remove function to a select field and I wanna preview the font family based upon the selected value. The code I wrote works well but every preview text gets reset when I add a new select field. What am I doing wrong?

```
@foreach($fontinputs as $key => $value)
 <select class="form-select" id="font.{{ $value }}">
   <option value="PT Sans" style="font-family:'PT Sans'">PT Sans</option>
   <option value="Roboto" style="font-family:'Roboto'">Roboto</option>
   <option value="Source Sans" style="font-family:'Source Sans'">Source Sans</option>
   <option value="Lato" style="font-family:'Lato'">Lato</option>
   <option value="Montserrat" style="font-family:'Montserrat'">Montserrat</option>
 </select>

 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" wire:click.prevent="removeFont({{$key}})">Remove</button>
                                
 <p id="fontpreview.{{ $value }}" class="p-3  fontpreview">Preview Text Here</p>

  <script>
   var obj{{ $value }} = document.getElementById('fontpreview.{{ $value }}');

   document.getElementById('font.{{ $value }}').addEventListener('change', function(){]

   obj{{ $value }}.style.setProperty("font-family", this.value, "important")

   });
 </script>
@endforeach
```

[Here is a preview of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWo1c.gif)

Comment: This is possibly because you have a foreach loop generating some parts of component.  Check out dom-diffing issues and solutions here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-issues 

I think you should wrap the code in the foreach in a single element like `div` and add `wire:key` should help.

Comment: @Coola Thanks! I was able to fix this by adding ```wire:ignore ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding `wire:ignore` to the elements within the foreach.